# Where is the "Local Guide to LaTeX for the McKludge PC" aka the Local Guide on Mac?

Tags: mactex

In Leslie Lamport's book, he refers to the local guide. I know the book's old, but Oetiker references it as well in the Not so short guide to LaTeX 2016 edition:

```
Each LATEX installation should provide a so-called LATEX Local Guide,
which explains the things that are special to the local system. It
should be contained in a file called local.tex. Unfortunately,
some lazy sysops do not provide such a document. In this case,
go and ask your local LATEX guru for help.
```

Y'all are the closest thing I know of to LaTeX gurus, so I appreciate your help. Does anyone know of where to find a working version of local.tex or better yet, a dvi or pdf version on Mac (I'm using TexLive 2017)?

Comment: Did you install MacTeX yourself? Then ***you*** are the sysop who is supposed to write `local.tex` explaining the features specific to the installation on your machine.

Comment: Please don't add random tags to posts - read the descriptions if you aren't sure what applies. `latex3` certainly doesn't.

Comment: These 'local guide' comments are from an era where each installation would be on a mainframe and customised (at the binary level) by the system administrator. Nowadays this isn't the case at all.

Comment: Is [the beginner document provided with MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/src/WelcomeToMacTeX.pdf) not good enough?

Comment: Or [the MacTeX wiki - starting points](http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php/Starting_Points)?

Comment: @cfr your first point is somewhat helpful, your second redundant given your edit.

Comment: @JosephWright you make an interesting point, but it is more likely just large installations than mainframes, I found several institutional versions of the file on the web.

Comment: @Thruston I didn't ask about beginner guides generally, but about the local guide specifically. JosephWright's comment got to the heart of the matter sufficiently. Two examples [Hong Kong Baptist College](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.75.3843&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [Rochester](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/twiki/pub/Main/TeXStuff/guide.pdf)

Comment: My second comment was intended to explain why I'd changed the tag and how to determine the correct tags in future. It isn't redundant to explain why-and-how. If I correct the tag silently, it tells you nothing about why and how to apply tags to your future questions.

Comment: @Thruston Mittelbach & Goossens in *The LaTeX Companion* (2nd end, p.11) warn: *most of the advice given in books about Plain TeX is either not applicable to LaTeX or, worse, produces subtle errors if used with LaTeX.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of further research, it would appear that the comments on the question are reasonably accurate. The local guide appears to be part of a bygone era. What few documents can be found online are specific to the system they reside on. None of the historical base packages contain the source for the guide. However, I did find the original 1988 document referred to in the [Rochester](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/twiki/pub/Main/TeXStuff/guide.pdf) local guide through a search that turned up a French [TeX history page](http://tex.loria.fr/historique/) that appears to be on its last legs, reminding me of how fragile our archival systems are, even today. This local guide by Lamport himself is [available here](http://tex.loria.fr/historique/local.pdf) in pdf form. Some text in the original document led me to a successful search for the LaTeX source which is currently [available here](http://www.uic.edu/depts/accc/software/tex/miscfiles/local.tex) at UIC. The [miscfiles directory](http://www.uic.edu/depts/accc/software/tex/miscfiles/) has local.tex's dependencies.